# In C#. Can i detect if my main is not responding or closing event when i'm in a while

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a little problem. I can detect the closing event of my main program, all is ok. But when i'm using a while to reach the end of a thread, i can't detect the closing event of my main program.
I can't detect if the main porgram is responding or not.

I always have the little window saying that my program (my main) is not responding... this information as given by Windows 10.

Why windows 10 can detect it and my program not ?

Have you got an idea on how can i detect the not responding event or closing event in my while loop ?

Thanks in advance.
Regards.

Comment: It would be better not to have a long running while-loop on your UI thread. If you have complex work, load it into a separate worker task so your UI remains responsive.

Comment: The OS owns the program and its threads, so it knows when they terminate. You should never terminate your program without closing any threads. Before .NET 4.0 programs used synchronization objects like AutoResetEvent to signal that a thread should terminate. Nowadays, programs use a CancellationTokenSource. Check, for example, [Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Asynchronous APIs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/). The Progress<T> and CancellationTokenSource classes aren't specific to `async/await`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @grek40. You should be using separate threads for long processes as to not freeze the UI (and result in the 'Not Responding' message).

Perhaps you can create a thread for checking the state of the main program that is separate from all other threads, especially the main UI thread.

```
    public async Task doSomething()
    {
        While(Condition)
        {
         //Check for event
        }

        //Or complete an action
    }
```

Or perhaps something like this:

```
new Thread(() =>
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;

            //Do something

        }).Start();
```

Comment: Ok, i try this and finally i use a timer. It's working.Thank you much. Your response is really great to create a thread with a sub-program.